# Change ion-toggle visual toggling with a variable value by true or false

Tags: javascript, html, angular, ionic-framework

I thought I had this done but no.

Somehow I can't make to change the toggling of my ion-toggle visual value, with a variable number.

I start my app with my variable at a false state, but my ion-toggle starts actively.

```html
<ion-toggle
  checked="loyaltyCardActiveState"
  [ngModel]="loyaltyCardActiveState"
  (click)="activeLoyaltyCard()"
></ion-toggle>
```

loyaltyCardActiveState is false at the start, but the toggle is active. What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You are using one way binding to your `[ngModel]`

Please change it to `[(ngModel)]` It'll change toggling visual value.

Let me know if it works

Answer (score 0):

use ionChange event:

```
`<ion-toggle
  checked="loyaltyCardActiveState"
  [ngModel]="loyaltyCardActiveState"
  (ionChange)="activeLoyaltyCard()"
></ion-toggle>`
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<ion-toggle
  [checked]="loyaltyCardActiveState"
  (ionChange)="activeLoyaltyCard()">
</ion-toggle>
```

Comment: Are there any more details?

Comment: Please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). While this code block may answer the OP's question, this answer would be much more useful if you explain how this code is different from the code in the question, what you've changed, why you've changed it and why that solves the problem without introducing others. - [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/32238228)